# Why is limiting equality true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis

I meet the following equation in a textbook:

$$\prod_{i=0}^m \left(1-\frac{4i}{n(n-1)(n-2)-2i(n-2)}\right) = 1+O\left(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}\right),$$

where $m=\frac{1}{2}n(\log n+\omega(n)),\omega(n)=o(\log n)$ and $|\omega(n)|$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

I wonder why it is true. And I think it may use the Taylor's formula for $\log(1-x)$ when $x$ is small if taking log both sides. But I don't know how to deal with $2\log\log n$ on the RHS.

Comment: @Winther Yes, I revised the typo.

Comment: @Yikai I guess it means the error can be bounded by the last term.